# Would an afterburner on a turbine drastically improve acceleration lag?

Tags: thermodynamics, automotive-engineering, turbines, car

A little bit of context. My friends and I were watching the "Dark Knight Rises" and a discussion about the Batmobiles ensued. I, being a former ME student, said it was stupid that batman has a turbine in his car at all because they aren't responsive enough for the very Fast and Furious way Batman tends to drive. Batman seems to need a car with an engine that can produce a lot of power and adjust its power output very quickly; Batman needs a car without much acceleration lag. Turbines can produce a lot of power, but they simply can't be responsive. I suggested Batman use a rocket instead, though he should probably just be using some turbo and super chargers or be driving an electric vehicle at this point.

At this point my friend, with an English degree, said that Batman did in fact have a rocket on the back of his car, and pointed out that the jet engine in the Batmobile has flames coming out of the back of it, which means it has an afterburner. He then argued that would make the Batmobile responsive enough for the driving style to be fine.

I disagree, but I can't find any sources on how an afterburner actually effects the responsiveness of a turbine. After looking I learned that an afterburner produces extra thrust. My thought is that the turbine would already need to be working in order for an afterburner to do anything. In a car that would still lead to a responsiveness problem right?

Can an afterburner make the turbine in Batman's Batmobile responsive enough satisfy his insane driving requirements?

Comment: The only car that I know of that did have a gas turbine engine was made by Rover... wasn't it the IS60?

Comment: @SolarMike Not sure, I know that there's a tank with a turbine in it.

Comment: @Steve  Yes, there are tuboshaft-powered tanks.  Notably: T-80 and M1 Abrams.  I don't know how they deal with turbine, unfortunately.  [I wonder if there would be any merit to rewrite this question in the context of production tanks, rather than fictional Batmobiles.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev I could, but a tank doesn't need to be able to do stunt driving. The fictional vehicle does. I did some research and there were apparently some turbine powered vehicles. I've only found one that didn't have a huge acceleration lag issue and that vehicle didn't have an afterburner.

Comment: @Steve  Tank are designed to do energetic maneuvering.  This includes stopping and rapidly backing up to get out of the enemy antitank fire.

Comment: @NickAlexeev at 80mph while drifting?

Comment: @Steve  80km/h.  40 to 50 metric tons.  Turbine doesn't care about drift.

Comment: @NickAlexeev use information about tanks in your answer then.